# Random selection and repeat a specific amount of times for each selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, repeat

I want to get a random selected item from an array up till how many maximum repeat time specified.

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
var maxRepeat = 10;
```

I want to return cat and dog each 10 times which make a total of 20 times in a random order.
Something like:

```
cat
cat
dog
cat
dog
dog
cat
cat
dog
cat
dog
dog
dog
cat
cat
dog
cat
cat
dog
dog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
var maxRepeat = 10;
var occObj= {};


for(var i = 0; i < array.length * maxRepeat; i++){
    var  occ = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

    if(occObj[occ]){
        if(occObj[occ].count < maxRepeat){
            occObj[occ].count++;
            console.log(occ);
        }else{
            i--; //if the particular value was displayed "maxRepeat" times already, we need to make sure we run the loop again
        }   
    }else{
        occObj[occ] = {}
        occObj[occ].count = 1;
        console.log(occ);
    }
}
```

I am using object to store how many times the particular value was displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `for` loop and then use push or unshift where both have 50% chance on each element.

```js
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
var maxRepeat = 10;

const random = function(arr, n) {
  var c = 0,r = [],total = n * arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var rand = Math.random() <= 0.5;
    var el = arr[c++ % arr.length]
    rand ? r.push(el) : r.unshift(el)
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(random(array, maxRepeat))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the following way

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}

let arr = ["cat", "dog"];
let temp = [];
for(let str of arr){
    temp = temp.concat(Array(10).fill(str));
}

shuffle(temp);
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you're asking for, but here's a function that will return a random `"cat"` or `"dog"` (10 times for each animal; after all animals have been exhausted, it will return `null`):

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"],
    maxRepeat = 10;

let getRandomAnimal = (() => {
        let totalAnimals = maxRepeat * array.length,
            animals = new Array(totalAnimals),
            index = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < totalAnimals; ++i) {
            animals[i] = array[i % array.length];
        }

        animals.sort(() => Math.floor(Math.random() - 0.5));

        return () => {
            return ((index >= totalAnimals) ? null : animals[index++]);
        };
    })();
```